# Can't throw exception in constructor of subclass

Tags: java

I made 3 classes: a brand class (Marca), a comercial brand class (MarcaComercial) which is a subclass of the brand class and an exception class (ExMarcaInvalida) if one of the attributes initiated in the brand constructor is null. I want to catch this exception in my subclass constructor and declare it  and use a setter method if this exception is caught. However, I can't do it because I can't initiate the values of the superclass anywhere other than the first line. Is there a way to catch the exception and do what I want? Leaving all 3 class constructors below.

```
public Marca(String nome, String produtor, String regiao) 
        throws ExMarcaInvalida {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.produtor = produtor;
    this.regiao = regiao;
    if(nome.isEmpty() || nome.isBlank()){
        throw new ExMarcaInvalida("Nome invalido");
    }
}
```

```
public MarcaComercial(String rotulo, String email, 
    String num, String nome,String produtor, String regiao) 
    throws ExMarcaInvalida {
    try{
        super(nome, produtor, regiao); //ISSUE HERE
        this.rotulo = rotulo;
        this.email = email;
        this.num = num;
    }
    catch(ExMarcaInvalida e){
        setRotulo("Marca Branca");
        throw new ExMarcaInvalida("Marca Invalida");
    }
}
```

```
public class ExMarcaInvalida extends Exception{
    public ExMarcaInvalida(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }  
}
```

Comment: What does it matter where construction fails? The object is not going to be constructed anyways. Also, you can't call setters after throwing.

Comment: but if I construct the object won't it set to that if the exception is caught?

Comment: You're throwing an exception anyway: `throw new ExMarcaInvalida("Marca Invalida");`, so what does calling the setter acheive?

Comment: @jorgefarnando How can you construct a valid object if the `super()` call fails and throws an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can't throw exception in constructor of subclass

The problem is NOT that you can't **throw** the exception.

The real problem is that you can't **catch** an exception thrown in a constructor's `super` call ... in the constructor itself.  The `super` call must be the first statement of the constructor, and that means it cannot be inside a `try ... catch`.

If you really need to catch the exception, you need to use a factory method to create the object; e.g.

```
public MarcaComercial makeMarcaComercial(...) {
    try {
        return new MarcaComercial(...);
    } catch (ExMarcaInvalida ex) {
        // This will catch the exception whether it is thrown by 
        // the Marca constrictor or the MarcaComercial constructor
        //
        // Now we can throw a new exception or return a different object.
    }
}
```

But even with a factory method, you can't "fix" and return the original object that you were creating.  That object is not accessible to the factory method.

Basically, Java is preventing you from returning an instance where the superclass initialization has failed.  It would be a broken abstraction, even it the fix made sense.  The subclass would need to know about the private details of the superclass implementation.  Anyhow ... Java doesn't allow it.

---

<sup>(Actually, I can think of a couple of *horrible* ways to subvert this ... but I won't describe them in case someone thinks they might be a good idea.)</sup>

Comment: got it now, thanks, sorry if it was kind of a stupid question but just now learning exceptions.

Comment: Not a stupid question, IMO.